# Debug PyDev+Eclipse - Code not reloads after code change in breakpoint/suspend mode

Tags: python, debugging, google-app-engine, pydev

I often doing such steps and want to optimize debug speed:

1. I am setting some breakpoints.
2. I am running Google Appengine Application (Python 2.5.2+).
3. When breakpoint occur I often change code to fix bugs.
4. After code change want to test again but there is problem if I changed code in breakpoint/suspend mode the application **does not updates** with my **code changes** - thus requiring a slow reloading.

Does anybody have an idea of what is root cause of forcing reloading after suspend or it is PyDev Bug/Limitation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way the debug works is not by executing the *source* line-by-line. **The debug "compiles" your source to bytecode (the .pyc files) and execute those, not your source**.

The debug only keeps track of what piece of the .pyc files correspond to what line of your .py ones and display that information for your convenience, but the .py file itself is not what the debugger is using to run the program.

Therefore, if you change the source / .py file and want the debugger to acknowledge those changes, you need to "recompile" the .pyc files first.

HTH!

Comment: So you suggest that problem is rather that eclipse not rebuild code after source change so new *.pyc is not generated from *.py. I will check it soon.

Comment: @Chameleon - When a python program is run, a thread is launched that executes the pyc code that was available at that moment (in most of the cases this code is loaded into memory before being executed). You can't alter that code once the program is launched. The only thing you can do is STOP the execution, generate new pyc files and run them instead with a NEW launch. In other words: what PyDev is doing is the only way debugging is done. The extra slowness is probably due to the fact that Eclipse has the speed of a lame bradypus... :(

Comment: When program is loaded I saw that there is two paths if I alter code and it is **not** in breakpoint mode - it alters program or it is in breakpoint mode - it not alters program. I will try to force rebuild today in breakpoint mode it should be faster than reload. If Pydev will suport such rebuild it will be faster after code alter.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. Mac, are you saying PyDev does or does not support reloading / recompiling modules without restarting GAE? The [PyDev+GAE video demonstrates](http://youtu.be/aoD5R_GX-08?t=7m42s) it working, though it doesn't for me on Mac OS X. @Chameleon, what OS are you on? If I take PyDev and Eclipse out of the equation, GAE does recompile the .pyc file when I change a source .py file, so it seems like maybe a bug in PyDev.

Comment: Sometime you can feel others that others - it is not strange :) Consider that difference in behavior is DEBUG and NOT DEBUG modes - as I explained there problem with DEBUG mode. OS is not related to it - it is WinXP or Win7 - not bet money on OS.